# How to grab 'show tech' with bash and expect?

Tags: bash, expect, cisco

I'm using 2 scripts. A bash and an expect script. the bash is just a for loop with a set of IPs. If I can, I would use the expect script to create a variable near the beginning, right after login. It would look for the hostname, assign it to a variable, then use that variable as the 'match' after show tech output.

Also, the IPs are example. I'm not actually expecting (no pun intended) this to operate on public DNS IPs. Ok ok, you got me, I put this disclaimer  here just so I could 'not' make that pun.

```
#!/bin/bash
arrayHOST+=( '8.8.8.8' '8.8.4.4' '4.2.2.2' '4.2.2.1' )
username="user1"; password="pass1"
for host in ${arrayHOST[@]}; do
    ./expect.sh $host $username $password >> $host.txt
done
```

and the expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#log_user 0
set timeout -1
set varIP1 [lindex $argv 0]
set varUSER [lindex $argv 1]
set varPASS [lindex $argv 2]
spawn telnet $varIP1
expect "Username:"
send "$varUSER\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$varPASS\n"
expect "#"
send "term leng 0\r"
expect "#"
send "term wid 0\r"
expect "#"
send "show tech\r"
expect "#"
puts $expect_out(buffer);
```

Problem is that there are '#' characters that match before the command finishes so I don't get to capture the whole thing. Points to consider:

- The end of the output from 'show tech' isn't the same on every device in the IP list unless you consider the hostname of the device itself.
- Yes, I know I can "show tech | redirect tftp:// etc". This wont help me achieve the desired results.
- I've tried 'not expecting anything' but this causes expect to not capture anything. (sending show tech without following with a new line containing expect "#" or anything else)

  ```
  spawn telnet 8.8.8.8
  Trying 8.8.8.8...
  Connected to 8.8.8.8.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  User Access Verification
  Username: benjamin
  Password: 
  rowtar#term leng 0
  rowtar#term wid 0
  rowtar#term wid 0
  rowtar#
  ```

I really like the idea of trying to regex/match an expect variable to the output that matches the hostname of the device but I don't how to do that. In my example, I would try to match "rowtar#" but without per-defining that ahead of time or before the expect script is called.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was looking me right in the face.
Simply:

```
expect -re #$
```

matching any line ending with #
I still encourage someone to help/answer with hostname matching to a variable